# Vue 2 google-map won't render in storybook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, storybook, vue2-google-maps

I'm using [vue2-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps) package and I have a working map component.
Now I try to create a story for this component in storybook and I get errors like:

`Unknown custom element <GmapMap>`

`Unknown custom element <GmapMarker>`

`Unknown custom element <GmapInfoWindow>.`

This is my story:

```
export default {
  title: "Components/GoogleMap",
  component: GoogleMap,
  argTypes: {
    size: {
      options: ["big"],
      control: "radio"
    }
  }
};

const Template = (args, { argTypes }) => ({
  props: Object.keys(argTypes),
  components: { GoogleMap },
  template: `<GoogleMap v-bind="$props" />`
});

export const Big = Template.bind({});
Big.args = {
  size: "big",
  addresses: [...]
};

export const Small = Template.bind({});
Small.args = {
  ...
};
```

Anyone have any idea for this?